# How to convert a pandas column to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, performance, datetime, series

I have a dataframe `df`

```
df
    date   
0  05/01/2017
1  04/01/2017
2  08/01/2017
3  03/01/2017
4  10/01/2017
```

I want to convert the column `date` from `str` to `datetime`

I am doing like the following

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

but it takes infinite time and if I try

```
pd.to_datetime(df['date'][0])
```

I get the following error

```
year is out of range
```

Comment: The code looks fine. I do the same on like 10 million records usually and it works fine.

Comment: To increase efficient use the format parameter in pd.to_datetime.  And, the "year is out of range" is probably due to bad data.

Answer (score 2):

Specify `format` or `infer_datetime_format` to see a massive performance boost:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10000)

%timeit pd.to_datetime(df['date'])                              # 12.5 s per loop
%timeit pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%m/%d/%Y')           # 252 ms per loop
%timeit pd.to_datetime(df['date'], infer_datetime_format=True)  # 228 ms per loop
```

Telling Pandas in advance what you expect is generally a good way to improve performance. So this idea will work with `pd.read_csv` too if you are reading from an input file.

Your error is likely due to poor data. If you wish to return `NaT` for non-convertible values, specify `errors='coerce'`:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%m/%d/%Y', errors='coerce')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],infer_datetime_format=True)
```

From pandas official docs, **Passing infer_datetime_format=True can often-times speedup parsing if its not an ISO8601 format exactly, but in a regular format** like the one you are passing